# Is there any way to display my comment votes?

Tags: support, voting, comments

Seems that the only way to see how votes have my comments is going comment by comment and checking it. Is there a better way to display my comment's votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Data Explorer with the following query which shows how many comments of yours has a certain number of votes:

- [My Comment Score distribution (user 96174)](http://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution?userid=96174)

There is a delay between the actual data and the Data Explorer's data dump. You can check when the Data Explorer was last updated using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede).

If you want a live list of your comments with comment score, you can use the API:

- [api.stackexchange.com/me/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-comments)